# Sharepoint 2013 Choice column validation

Tags: validation, sharepoint

We have a choice column in a custom list, displayed as a dropdown.  Because users were liable to simply choose the first value, the default value was set to "- Select -"

We're trying to find a way to use validation settings to let users know that if the default value is chosen, it is not a valid choice.

I have found an article that suggests that a choice column cannot have validation applied. Is that true?

If validation is possible, does anyone have suggestions on the correct syntax to use? We've tried =IF([Category]="- Select -",FALSE,TRUE) but that does not display any user message.

And after applying this formula it is not allowing to create a list item if category is not changed.

Can any one help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the use of event receivers on sharepoint lists ! You can manage perfectly these kind of controls with them.

Comment: But it should work with Client Side code Server side code is not involved.

Comment: The validation provided by sharepoint and which you are trying to use is so limited! for exemple, you can not control the error message that should be prompted to the end user! so like I said, event receivers are more powerful despite it runs on server side! if you are worried about the time of response, you can try it and you will see the difference!